# Arc draw with imperfections

Tags: php, gd, libpng

This is my php file (**arc.php**) which should produce a thick half arc:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(2000, 1000);    
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagesetthickness($img, 200);
imagearc($img, 1000, 1000, 1900, 1900,  180, 360, $white);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

The image is generated via cli:

```
php arc.php > arc.png
```

So far, so good...Now, does somebody know why do I get those imperfections in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [comments in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetthickness.php#usernotes) for `imagesetthickness` seem to imply that ellipses and arcs don't play nice with thickness settings.  Whether or not this is a bug or a feature is debateable.  Regardless, the suggested workaround is using a small thickness and repeatedly drawing the shape larger and larger.

In your case, it would look something like:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(2000, 1000);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

// Slightly thicker than 1 pixel to compensate pixel aliasing
imagesetthickness($img, 2);

$thickness = 200;
for ($i = $thickness; $i > 0; $i--) {
    imagearc($img, 1000, 1000, 1900 - $i, 1900 - $i,  180, 360, $white);
}

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Which generates the following image:[image]
You will probably need to adjust the results a bit, but this should be enough to get you started down the correct path.

Comment: Did the same thing, just fogetting to set the thickness = 2. This did the trick. Thanks. By the way regarding if it is a bug or not, I would say so... If it can be used with arc, then it should also behave as expected!... =)